# basic multiplying code not working

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    int l, r, c;

    printf("Enter the integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    printf("Enter the integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &r);

    c = 0; // product

    while(r != 0) { 

        if(r & '\x01' == 1) { 
          c = c + l; 
        }
        l = l << 1; 
        r = r >> 1;       
    }

    printf("the product is %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

It works when first integer entered is positive/negative and second is positive. But when the second integer entered is negative, it runs nonstop.

Comment: You were expecting that `r` will eventually become zero after shifting all the bits. When a signed int has signed bit on, it prepends 1 instead of 0 on  `>>` shift. By changing the definition from `int l, r, c;` to `unsigned int l, r, c;` it should work as intended.

Comment: @alvits: The OP seems to intend to be able to multiply negative numbers....

Comment: @Hurkyl - Unsigned int can hold the bit representations of signed ints. However, the behavior in shifting differs. The OP is operating on bits not on signed ints. The behavior that the OP is expecting is an unsigned int behavior. Negative numbers will still work as printf will print using `%d`, not `%u`. If in doubt, I encourage you to test it.

Comment: u should learn to use a debugger, you would immediately see that r is not doing what u expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the bit shift on your negative number, you can never get to 0.

```
r = r >> 1; // if r is negative, this will never be 0
```

This is due to the way [negative numbers are stored](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/239038/163680) in most C implementations.
You can verify it by doing:

```
int a = -1 >> 1; // a == -1, not 0!
```

To fix your issue, you need to first introduce a variable:

```
bool isNeg = r < 0;
if (isNeg)
{
    r = -r;
}
```

Now you can proceed as before:

```
while (...) { }
```

Don't forget to change the sign of the result of the multiplication at the end of the while loop:

```
if (isNeg)
{
    c = -c;
}
```

Comment: You should mention that the result of `r >> 1` is *implementation-defined*. Some systems may fill with zero bits , or anything else. Filling with 1-bits is the most common .

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, shifts on negative numbers aren't going to work like you need.

A few things:

First, your comments on the shifts of l and r are backwards...you're commenting the shift is right when it's left, and left when it's right. Obviously that's just commentary.

To fix this, you need to respond to r being negative with a "special case".

if ( r < 0 ) { r = -r; l = -l }

Now the loop works and correct results are produced.

This 'corrects' the requirement that you test the shifting r, while preserving sign for the result.